# SSRS Line Chart - highlight area

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I am trying to create an SQL reporting chart that looks like this:
[image]

Specifically, I am having a trouble with this red area. Any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What is your issue then?

Comment: My problem is how to create the red box to highlight chart's area.

Comment: I think this could possibly be accomplished by using stripline(s) on the Time axis.

Comment: Yes, good idea. I tried that. But striplines go across the whole chart area vertically or horizontally. There is no way to set start and end points.

Comment: You can add one strip line and give it an offset value and a set width, but yes your are right it will cover the entire vertical area.  Could you make a giant point on the line in that area?

Comment: Seems like using a range chart added to the line chart gives me what I want.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Kidiskidvogingogin, you can add a strip line to your horizontal axis, but it will cover the entire vertical axis. Remember to set the offset according to your needs.

For example, if you have dates, days can be used, with an offset of n days from the start. The highlighted area's width is also set as n days - both of which you can calculate n the fly.

For example, a quick report that highlight's this month's repot data on a running 12 month chart:
[image: Strip line example]

As an example of the intervals and calculations for the above:
[image: Strip line interval options]